# Unit tests with with assert raise exception

Tags: python, exception, python-unittest

I just stumbled over this type of code and am bit puzzled by its functionality in unit tests:

```
with self.assertRaises(MyException):
    foo(some_value)
```

where `foo` throws `MyException`

How does this fit together?

Comment: The context manager catches the exception.  What's the question, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This is the test of function `foo` that checks whether it raises `MyException` or not. The test has positive result if it does, otherwise, it's result is negative.